# Why are all my double precision calculations in a loop give the same results?

Tags: c++, loops

I have some trouble doing this question:

> Your first program is a simple mathematical calculation program. The program will take inputs from the user. Evaluate *f*(*x*) and display the results in a table. The inputs from the user will be: two `double`s `xmin` and `xmax`. A symbolic constant (`POINTS`) is used to determine the number of rows in the table. The equation is the sum of two cosine functions;
>
> *f*(*x*) = 0.0572 cos(4.667 *x*) + 0.0218 π cos(12.22 *x*);  [Equation 1]
>
> Hint:
>
> - You may use the function `cos` found in `<cmath>`, in your calculations.
> - The value for π is a named constant, and its value is 3.1416;
>
> Approach:
>
> 1. Define a symbolic constant (`POINTS`) to set the number of rows to 20,
> 2. Ask the user for the values of `xmin` and `xmax`;
> 3. Using the three values above (`POINTS`, `xmin` and `xmax`) compute the values for increments on `x`;
> 4. Use Equation 1 to compute the values of *f*(*x*);
> 5. Display a table with the following format:
>
> Assume the value for `POINTS` is 21, and the user enters `xmin` = −2 and `xmax` = 2; then your program should display a table like:
>
> ```
> X-Value   |   Y-Value
> __________|__________
>  -2           -0.0043
>  -1.8         -0.0982
>  -1.6         +0.0378
>  -1.4         +0.0438
>  -1.2         +0.0099
>  -1           +0.0618
>  -0.8         -0.1118
>  -0.6         -0.0198
>  -0.4         -0.0047
>  -0.2         -0.0184
>  0            +0.1257
>  0.2          -0.0184
>  0.4          -0.0047
>  0.6          -0.0198
>  0.8          -0.1118
>  1             0.0618
>  1.2           0.0099
>  1.4           0.0438
>  1.6           0.0738
>  1.8          -0.0982
>  2            -0.0043
> ─────────────────────
> ```

So far I got parts 1 to 4 but I'm am struggling with part 5. Here is what I have for my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#define pi 3.1416
#define POINTS 20
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int Xmin, Xmax;
    int step;

    cout << "Enter a value for xMin and xMax:\n";
    cin >> Xmin >> Xmax;
    double x, y;
    step = (Xmax - Xmin) / POINTS;

    cout << "X-VALUES " << "" << "| " << "" << "Y-VALUES" << endl;
    cout << "_________" << "" << "|_" << "" << "_________" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < POINTS; ++i) 
    {
        x = Xmin + (step * i);

        y = 0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * pi * cos(12.22 * x);


        cout << x << "\t " << y << endl;
    }
    cout << "____________________" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It does everything, except it does not print the right values. here is what it prints from my code:

```
Enter a value for xMin and xMax:
-2
2

    X-Value   |   Y-Value
    __________|__________
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
     -2           -0.0043
    ─────────────────────
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong. I can't get the values exactly like the table on top in part 5. It 's just repeating itself 20 times. The `i` increments by one so shouldn't I see a value change on the next increment when the program outputs the `x` and `y`? Help me, I'm so confused.

Comment: `step = (Xmax - Xmin) / POINTS;` This will be calculated in integer arithmetic, and for `xmin = -2 and xmax = 2` will result in `step = 0`.

Comment: `int step;` should be `double step;` also calculate it as `step = (double)(Xmax - Xmin) / (double)POINTS;`.

Comment: Please note that your program may run differently due to floating point inaccuracies.  Your `step` calculation may be off by 1 if you used the same values, but built the program using different compiler options, or if you used a different compiler.

Comment: @Puppy That's not a valid close reason, find an approprite dupe or shut up! The only valid close reason I could think of is _"Questions asking for debugging help ..."_ because the OP obviosly missed to use the debugger in 1st place.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems with integer division and type precision.

1. Obviously you wan't to apply `step` with a `double` precision context, thus `step` itself should be declared as `double` type:

   ```
   double step = .0;
   ```
2. The expression `(Xmax - Xmin) / POINTS` lacks for integer division that can't provide values from the range *`+-]0-1.0[`*. To overcome the integer division issue make at least one operand being casted to `double`:

   ```
   double step = (double)(Xmax - Xmin) / POINTS;
   ```

<kbd>[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/grLyUS)</kbd>

Comment: Looks like the drive-by downvoters are on the prowl tonight. +1 from me.

Comment: @PeteBecker Puppy (speculativey suspected, because of their typical pattern) isn't really a drive-by downvoter, they have their reasonings and I understand why.

Answer (score -1):

First, use **initialization** instead of declaring a variable with no value and later assigning a value to it. So, for example, remove `double x, y;` and change these two lines:

```
x = Xmin + (step * i);
y = 0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * pi * cos(12.22 * x);
```

to these:

```
double x = Xmin + (step * i);
double y = 0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * pi * cos(12.22 * x);
```

That makes it much easier to see what types are involved in expressions like those.

Now do the same for the variable `step`. If the problem isn't immediately obvious when you do that, add an output statement that shows the value of `step`.

Comment: Whether to perform initialization or assignment is mostly a stylistic choice. Can you explain how it would make a significant difference in his result?

Comment: @Barmar - it would make it clear what the type of `step` is at the point where its value is first set and, shortly after that, when it is used (although I'd move its initialization down to just above the loop; it's current placement is more or less random). And, since this question is tagged C++, it's not "mostly a stylistic choice"; it's sometimes a matter of correctness, and often a matter of efficiency. For the first, imagine a type that has no default constructor; for the second, a default constructor that's very expensive. Uninitialized variables should be quite rare in C++.

Comment: @Barmar - further, even in languages like C that don't have constructors, initialization is far safer (to use a grossly overloaded term) than creating an uninitialized variable with the intention of assigning a value to it later.